# Does the sequence $x_{n}=(1, ... , 1, 0,0,...)$ (with $n$ ones) converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the sequence $x_{n}=(1, ... , 1, 0,0,...)$ (with $n$ ones) converge?
In the linear space of sequences $x=(x_{1},x_{2},..)$ $(x_{k}\in\mathbb{R})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}^{2}<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If the sequence converges, then the sequence of norms must also converge, i.e. if $$x_1,x_2,\dots$$
converges, then $$|x_1|, |x_2|, \dots$$ must also converge.

Comment: And how to prove that norms are converge?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko Dude. I am **not** going to write out every part of the step for you. Either you do some work yourself, or don't expect any answers from me.

Comment: Sequence of norms will be $\sqrt{n}$ for every $n\geqslant 0$. And this sequence doesn't converge. Right?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko: $\|x\|-\|x_n\|\leq \|x-x_n\|$. Since the r.h.s. goes to 0 (is bounded) and $\|x_n\|$ is finite for all $n$, it follows that $\|x\|$ is finite as well, since it doesn't depend on $n$.