# Help with proving

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

In the linear space of sequences $x=( x_{1}, x_{2}, ... ), (x_{k}\in \mathbb{R})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }x_{k}^{2}<\infty$. 
Let $(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\lambda_{k}x_{k}y_{k}$, where $\lambda_{k}\in \mathbb{R}, 0<\lambda_{k}<1$. Will the resulting Euclidean space be Hilbertian?

Answer:

No. Let sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\lambda_{k}$ is converge and for choosing $\varepsilon>0$ number $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty }\lambda_{k}<\varepsilon$. Let's choose sequence $x_{n}=(1,..,1,0,0 ... )$ with $n$ ones. Then if $m,n>N$ we have that $ \left \| x_{m} - x_{n}  \right \|<\varepsilon
$ but $x_{n}$ doesn't converge.

Questions:
Why $x_{n}$ doesn't converge and why  $ \left \| x_{m} - x_{n}  \right \|<\varepsilon$? And why this is enough for proving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does $x_n$ not converge?

You already asked this question and I already answered it here: [Does the sequence $x_{n}=(1, ... , 1, 0,0,...)$ (with $n$ ones) converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006779/does-the-sequence-x-n-1-1-0-0-with-n-ones-converge/2006783#2006783)

---

> Why $\|x_m-x_n\|<\epsilon$?

Well, technically, it should be $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, but that doesn't change the proof. You can see why it's $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ if you write out

$$\|x_m-x_n\| = \|(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots)\| = \sqrt{((0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots),(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots))}$$

---

> And why this is enough for proving?

Because you have proven that there exists a non-convergent Cauchy sequence, therefore the statement "Every Cauchy sequence is convergent" (i.e. the **definition** of a Hilbert space) is false.

Comment: How we use information that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty }\lambda_{k}<\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko What, by definition, is $$\sqrt{((0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots),(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots))}?$$ Use the definition of the dot product to calculate this number.

Comment: The number of ones will be $m-n$ ?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko Yes, but what will the inner product of these two sequences be? Remember, by definition, $$(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\lambda_{k}x_{k}y_{k}$$

so, what do you get if $x=y=(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots)$?

Comment: It will be $\sum_{k=n}^{m}\lambda_{k}$ and it will be less then $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko There you go.

Comment: But how to prove that $x_{n}$ doesn't converge?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko I answered that question when you first asked it.

Comment: @M.Shumeiko http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006779/does-the-sequence-x-n-1-1-0-0-with-n-ones-converge/2006783#2006783

Comment: How the sequence of norms looks like?

Comment: @M.Shumeiko I will discuss that question where you first asked it.